# Appending XElement to existing XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following XML string in database.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ServiceList>
   <Service>
    <COMPAT>2</COMPAT>
    <EQUIPID>0</EQUIPID>
    <TITLE>Collect Call and SMS</TITLE>
    <SMSCOMMAND>0</SMSCOMMAND>
    <DIALCOMMAND>123</DIALCOMMAND>
    <DEACTIVATIONCOMMAND>0</DEACTIVATIONCOMMAND>
    <MODE>Dial</MODE>
    <DETAIL>Here you go.</DETAIL>
    <IMAGE>2014-16-9--16-28-25</IMAGE>
    <LONGDESC>
        <![CDATA[<p>P<br />P<br />P&nbsp;</p>]]>
    </LONGDESC>
    <Mechanism>
        <Title>Mech Title</Title>
        <Description>Here you go.</Description>
        <Trigger>Mech Trigger</Trigger>
        <Controls>1</Controls>
    </Mechanism>
   </Service>
 </ServiceList>
```

I need to add/appened the following element inside ServiceList

```
<Service>
 <COMPAT>2</COMPAT>
 <EQUIPID>0</EQUIPID>
 <TITLE>Collect Call and SMS</TITLE>
 <SMSCOMMAND>0</SMSCOMMAND>
 <DIALCOMMAND>123</DIALCOMMAND>
 <DEACTIVATIONCOMMAND>0</DEACTIVATIONCOMMAND>
 <MODE>Dial</MODE>
 <DETAIL>Here you go.</DETAIL>
 <IMAGE>2014-16-9--16-28-25</IMAGE>
 <LONGDESC><![CDATA[<p>P<br />P<br />P&nbsp;</p>]]></LONGDESC>
 <Mechanism>
    <Title>Mech Title</Title>
    <Description>Here you go.</Description>
    <Trigger>Mech Trigger</Trigger>
    <Controls>1</Controls>
 </Mechanism>
</Service>
```

The c# code is given below where i am creating the document

```
            XElement ServiceList =
                new XElement("ServiceList",
                    new XElement("Service",
                        new XElement("COMPAT", "2"),
                        new XElement("EQUIPID", equipId),
                        new XElement("TITLE", form["Title"]),
                        new XElement("SMSCOMMAND", smscommand),
                        new XElement("DIALCOMMAND",dialcommand),
                        new XElement("DEACTIVATIONCOMMAND", smsdecactivationcommand),
                        new XElement("MODE", mode),
                        new XElement("DETAIL", form["Detail"]),
                        new XElement("IMAGE", Datetime),
                        new XElement("LONGDESC", new XCData(htmlstring)),
                        new XElement("Mechanism",
                                new XElement("Title", form["Mechanism.Title"]),
                                new XElement("Description", form["Mechanism.Description"]),
                                new XElement("Trigger", form["Mechanism.Triger"]),
                                new XElement("Controls", form["Mechanism.Controls"])
                            )
                        ));

            XDocument xml = new XDocument(ServiceList);
```

I simply convert the above document to string with the help of the following method and insert it to database as string.

```
    public string GetXMLAsString(XDocument myxml)
    {

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        XmlTextWriter tx = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
        myxml.WriteTo(tx);

        string str = sw.ToString(); 
        return str;
    }
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused: do you read the XML from the database or do generate it every time? If it's already in the database, why are trying to add to it? Are you actually trying to create the XML and save it in the database?

Comment: what i want is to generate xml document once from code which could be saved to database as string . then whenever i need to add element i will fetch that xml document string and append xElement to it. i just want to know how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're able to get the XML string back from database and store it in a string variable `xml`, then you can load it to `XDocument` as follow :

```
string xml;
.....
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
```

And assuming that you can construct the new `<Service>` node as an `XElement` object referenced by variable `newService`, you can easily append it to the `doc` using [`XElement.Add()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb354061%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method :

```
XElement newService;
.....
doc.Root.Add(newService);
```

Then you need to replace the XML in your database with updated XML :

```
string updatedXml = doc.ToString();
//save updatedXml to your database
```

You can easily get XML content by calling [`ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341005%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the `XDocument` object, as shown in above example.